# Can't resolve names

Tags: networking, dns

Trying configure DNS service for old Linux machine. Network runs fine and ping by ip reaches internet. But if I ping by name `ping www.google.com` command just hangs for long time and brings answer: `ping: unknown host www.google.com`

```
/etc/network/interfaces:


# Used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8). See the interfaces(5) manpage or
# /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples for more information.

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface uses static address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.99
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        network 192.168.1.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

How to fix DNS service?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the line

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

to

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

and execute in terminal

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Does the `ping www.google.com` work after that?

Comment: I'd recommend `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`. Then, you get 192.168.1.1 in case there's a WiFi login page or domains on the local network (which 8.8.8.8 won't know about) that you need to access, you get [Cloudflare's fast DNS servers](https://1.1.1.1/), and you get Google's less-fast DNS servers as a backup.

Comment: `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` and `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` not allows ping google by name